# add_rewrite_rule on default post type

Tags: permalinks, rewrite-rules

I need to add some rewrite rules on my posts in order to have one or more urls for the same post. E.g `/foo/post-name` and `bar/post-name` should lead the same post. I'm using this function:

```
function addRewritePost() {
    add_rewrite_rule( '^foo/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
    add_rewrite_rule( '^bar/([^/]+)/?', 'index.php?name=$matches[1]', 'top' );
}
add_action('init','addRewritePost');
```

This code redirects from `foo/post-name` to `/post-name` and I don't want this kind of behaivor.
How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be bad practice, since WordPress already has a functionality to do this built in. Rewriting the built in functionality is never a good idea.

To achieve this the best way is to use Taxonomies.

Lets say you create two categories:

1. Foo
2. Bar

Now select the categories for the post in question and setup your permalinks structure to be `/%category%/%postname%/` and you will get:

- foo/post-name
- bar/post-name

Hope this helps.